# Force Kubernetes to dispatch request over all Pods

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

For one of my projects, I am deploying the application on Kubernetes.

Shortly explained, the app (in my dev machine) is deployed on 8 pods (1 / cpu core), inside a Node.
Each pod can process one request at a time (I force the limite with a threadpool - CPU is the bottleneck here).

I would like to force Kubernetes load balancer to send incoming request to next pod when a pod is "busy".

Does any of you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Kube-proxy in IPVS mode which allows routing of services based on a few different algorithms. You can find more in the [documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs), and [this blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/). From the blog:

- You will need to run Kube proxy with a flag `--proxy-mode=ipvs`
- And add a flag `--ipvs-scheduler` for choosing one of the options

  `rr: round-robin`

  `lc: least connection`

  `dh: destination hashing`

  `sh: source hashing`

  `sed: shortest expected delay`

  `nq: never queue`

As a pre-requisite the nodes will need the following modules installed:

```
ip_vs
ip_vs_rr
ip_vs_wrr
ip_vs_sh
nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

If you want to do more sophisticated routing than this - then I would look into service mesh as an option